# Decompiling of .apk files

Tags: android

How to decode the .apk files, I followed http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/    but ddx.jar didnot produce any output file.

Answer (score 4):

Check out APKTool. [Original XDA post by Brut.all](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=640592). [Google Code-page](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Answer (score 3):

Hope the below link will satisfy your need :
[Decompile your apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=722993)

Thanks,
Sen